# Connecting to HiveMetaStore on cluster with kerberos

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I have a java application which reads hive metadata using hcatalog apis. If I need to read metadata from a hive database on a cluster with Kerberos and knox, would the following configuration work?

```
HiveConf hcatConf = new HiveConf();
hcatConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, “thrift://server1.example.com:9083”);
hcatConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORE_KERBEROS_PRINCIPAL, “hive/_HOST@example.COM”);
hcatConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORE_KERBEROS_KEYTAB_FILE, “local_path/hive.keytab”);
hcatConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORE_USE_THRIFT_SASL, “true”);
HCatClient  hcatClient = HCatClient.create(new Configuration(hcatConf));
```

I will be running the Java program from a remote windows machine.

If my hive-site.xml on the cluster contains the following properties

```
< property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value>thrift://server1.example.com:9083</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
<description>If true, the metastore thrift interface will be secured with SASL. Clients must authenticate with Kerberos.</description>
< /property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file</name>
<value>/etc/hive/conf/hive.keytab</value>
<description>The path to the Kerberos Keytab file containing the metastore thrift server’s service principal.</description>
< /property>
<property>
<name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
<value>hive/_HOST@example.COM</value>
<description>The service principal for the metastore thrift server. The special string _HOST will be replaced automatically with the correct host name.</description>
< /property>
```

how do I configure the HCatClient to connect to hive?

Comment: Looks like you've been asking in many places and no one knows how the damn thing works. Did you consider using a JDBC connection to run "metadata" commands such as `describe extended`, `show partitions`, `alter table`?

Comment: BTW the Oozie committers appear to do it that way: https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/HCatCredentialHelper.java

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/21993/hcatalog-and-kerberos.html